# form figure with css and vue

Tags: css, vue.js

I am trying to create this figure on my site, I am working with CSS and Vue, but so far I am not achieving this goal, I am really new to this

My objective:

[image]

What i have so far:

[image]

I have not really managed to make it look like the first image, any advice on how I can do it, since I am really new to this

```
<div id="paralelogramored" class="forma"></div>
  <div id="paralelogramowhite" class="forma">
    <a Class="">Iniciar Sesion</a>
    <img style="float:left;" src="./assets/scss/images/loginLogo.png" class="imgLogin"/>
  </div>
```

my css

```
        .imgLogin{
          width: 20px;
        }

        .forma{
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 16px;
        }

        #paralelogramored {
           width: 150px; 
           height: 50px; 
           background: red;
           -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg); 
           -moz-transform: skew(-20deg); 
           -o-transform: skew(-20deg); 
           padding-top: 0px;
        }
        #paralelogramowhite {
           width: 150px; 
           height: 50px; 
           background: white;
           -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg); 
           -moz-transform: skew(-20deg); 
           -o-transform: skew(-20deg); 
           padding-top: 0px;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create figure with css and vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291626/create-figure-with-css-and-vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the psuedo element `:before`. I've attached a quick example of what that could look like.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://www.topgear.com/sites/default/files/styles/16x9_1280w/public/images/news-article/2018/07/979c566babe3ae625a9ad7350c019677/a187611_large.jpg?itok=laveSilF) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

#banner {
  width: 380px;
  height: 55px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

#banner:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
  background: red;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}


#banner .content {
  margin-left: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
   <div class="content">
     Content is positioned here
   </div>
</div>
```